# How do I avoid an error in Lua when the user enters something wrong?

Tags: lua

I'm facing a problem in Lua that I can't solve as a beginner.
I have built a rock, paper and scissors game in Lua. It asks for a user query.
So far this works. I am now trying to add another IF or elseif query that will kick in if the value of the input is NIL or something other than numbers 1 to 3 or scissors rock paper.I had the idea so far:
No matter what version I come up with, I can't get it to work. anyone have any ideas ?
I hope to getting help

```
UserInput = function()
print("Scissors, Rock or Paper?")
local input = io.read()
if value[input] then
    return input
else
    local number = tonumber(input)
    return selection[number]
    end
end

if value[input] = nil then
local random = math.random(3)
return choice[random]
end
```

Comment: Wrap your code in a loop. If the user enters something wrong, print so and let the loop repeat the query. If the input was valid, return would leave the function and thus the loop.

Comment: You should also fix the indentation, it would let you see that your current code is definitely not what you want. The last 4 lines are outside the function.

Answer (score 0):

Using a lookup table for string <=> number conversions (generally useful in an RPS implementation):

```lua
local RPS = {
    [1] = 'rock',
    [2] = 'paper',
    [3] = 'scissors',
    ['rock'] = 1,
    ['paper'] = 2,
    ['scissors'] = 3
}
```

You could write a function such as

```lua
local function user_input(default_random)
    print('Rock (1), Paper (2), or Scissors (3) ?')
    local input = io.read()

    if input then
        local n = tonumber(input)
        local c = RPS[input:lower()] or RPS[n] and n

        if c then
            return c
        end
    end

    if default_random then                                          
        print('Invalid selection. Randomizing...')                                                                                                
        return math.random(3)
    end                                                                                                                                           
end
```

which can be used to default to a random value on bad input

```lua
while true do
    print("Got:", user_input(true))
end
```

```
Rock (1), Paper (2), or Scissors (3) ?
1
Got:    1
Rock (1), Paper (2), or Scissors (3) ?
paper
Got:    2
Rock (1), Paper (2), or Scissors (3) ?
4
Invalid selection. Randomizing...
Got:    3
Rock (1), Paper (2), or Scissors (3) ?
lizard
Invalid selection. Randomizing...
Got:    2
```

or otherwise return `nil`, allowing you to repeat the prompt:

```lua
while true do
    local input

    while true do
        input = user_input()

        if input then
            break
        end

        print('Invalid selection, please try again.')
    end

    print("Got:", input)
end
```

```
Rock (1), Paper (2), or Scissors (3) ?
1
Got:    1
Rock (1), Paper (2), or Scissors (3) ?
paper
Got:    2
Rock (1), Paper (2), or Scissors (3) ?
4
Invalid selection, please try again.
Rock (1), Paper (2), or Scissors (3) ?
lizard
Invalid selection, please try again.
Rock (1), Paper (2), or Scissors (3) ?
3
Got:    3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UserInput = function()
 print("Scissors, Rock or Paper?")
local input = io.read()
if value[input] then
 return input
else
 local number = tonumber(input)
 return selection[number]
end
end
-- **look here  " value[input] = nil "**
-- **I believe in you need use nil == value[input]**
if value[input] = nil then
 local random = math.random(3)
return choice[random]
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Exception Handling : 'nil' in value, if-else, tonumber() function

```
UserInput = function()
    print("Scissors, Rock or Paper?")
    local input = io.read()
    if value[input] then
        return input
    else
        local number = tonumber(input)
        if number and number >= 1 and number <= 3 then
            return selection[number]
        else
            local random = math.random(3)
            return choice[random]
        end
    end
end
```